# GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL equivalent on DirectX

Tags: directx

I'm trying to mix atlas and mipmapping for a kind of Minecraft editor I'm doing. Everything looks good until I reach the smaller mipmaps of the atlas texture, where obviously all the textures are mixed into one, looking horrible at the distance.

With OpenGL I'd use glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, n); to avoid this problem, but I'm unable to find the DirectX equivalent. Is it possible to do this in DirectX?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Of course, hours searching for clues, and few minutes after posting the question I find the answer :P

Most similar way to do what I want to do is MaxLOD of D3D10_SAMPLER_DESC:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172415%28VS.85%29.aspx